# Move randomly a plane with cut parts| Paper Furr

Tags: animation, particles, hair, force-fields

I am looking to create a sort of "flag", a plane with some cuts that are creating sort of "leaves" and I need to open these apertures with turbulence or wind.

Basically I need to recreate the same thing that is happening when you take a piece of paper and made a lot of cuts inside. When you will blow behind these little parts will open showing the hole of the paper

I tried with a particels system and vertex group. I created a surface with the holes and in a separated object, I have several "leaves" grouped with different vertex groups.
The static render is nice but for animation is absolutely not realistic and super heavy.
[image]

Is there any good way to approach this animation?
After I should shrinkwrap the entire thing on a curved surface that will be hidden.
Any suggestion?

Comment: You could try a cloth simulation and a wind force field. Pin the vertices that should be static

Comment: Thank you, I solved it! I watched some tutorials about flags, flying plastic bag and posters from IanHubert YouTube channel and I found a solution.
I made a plane as a piece of fabric, cut some faces and pinned all the vertex. Then I created the small faces with the same dimension of holes and let free to move with a wind force. Then playing with subdivision surfaces, boolean division and simply deform I get the right surface and shape of this "sail".

Thanks a lot! You saved me for my exam ahah

Comment: Please write your solution as a proper answer, not as a comment. Other users might find it useful. Save others for their exams...

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:
I watched some tutorials about flags, flying plastic bags and posters from IanHubert YouTube channel and I found the solution.
I made a plane as a piece of fabric, cut some faces and pinned all the vertex. Then I created the small faces with the same dimension of holes and let free to move with a wind force. Then playing with subdivision surfaces, boolean division and simply deform I get the right surface and shape of this "sail".